# can we execute tests from different maven projects in a single run using TestNG xml

Tags: selenium, maven, testng

I have separate maven projects for each module, and each project has it's own set of tests.
e.g. Project A: has test scripts- TC1, TC2.
Project B: has test scripts- TC3, TC4.
Project c: has test scripts- TC5, TC6.

Currently each project has TestNG.xml and I am running tests using TestNG xml. I need to trigger separate 3 runs, if I have to run all tests.

Now I want to run selective/all test scripts from each project in single run.

Can someone please tell me is it doable? if yes, then how to create TestNG xml and where it will be placed?

Comment: When you say separate maven projects, are you referring to a "Multi module" maven project?

Comment: Why do you need `TestNG.xml`?

Comment: You can create multiple profiles and then with the help of maven invoker you can execute different pom.xml based on the selection of the profiles. Tip: always use pom.xml to run testng.xml. Running the testng.xml present in the maven project could work fine in the IDE but when you will work any integration tool then maybe you will think about running the testng.xml with pom. Bottom line: always use pom.xml

Comment: @khmarbaise: why do I need this because currently we have 10 modules and all TCs needs to run for 3 different continents. to achieve this I need to create too many Jenkins jobs. Goal is to use single job to run all or selective modules on different continents.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan: yes, it is Multi module mave project

Comment: @UnknownBeast: yes, I am using pom.xml to run testNG xml through Jenkins job. Here I did not get what do you mean by create multiple profiles and selection of profiles. Could you please elaborate more on this? Thanks

Comment: For Project 1, Project 2 and Project 3 you can create three different profiles in the master pom.xml. In these profiles you will be able to configure the plugin say surefire differently to run specific testng.xml. There are many videos out there for creating and running the profiles in maven